# Do Nested If Statements within Foreach loops add to Computation Complexity more than just linearly?

Tags: performance, nested, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

I've started to run static code analysis on my solution and noticed my team has a section with a "code complexity" rating off the charts.

I looked into it and found **15 levels** of nested if statements, with a foreach loop on the outside, and 2 nest levels within.

I'm familiar with big O notation and the complexity of a dictionary lookup compared to a double for (foreach) loop turning into a polynomial increase of inefficiency as opposed to a linear increase.

However, does that mean that the if statements are causing any real further complexity?

Or is the issue really just the foreach within another foreach and the if statements are just a linear increase like as a bunch of case statements with fall through?

IE: is just more of a readability/maintainability issue than an actual effiiciency issue?

I realize that this is a sign of there likely being a better algorithm to handle what is being done here, but I'm looking for a mathematical understanding of the inefficiency from the if statements within the foreach statements if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking at Cyclomatic Complexity. There many be an large amount of paths your code can partake because of the number of if statements. Imagine a Tree with roots reaching down and every if statement is a split in the roots where they branch in different directions.

There would be a lot of individual root paths!

> Cyclomatic complexity is a software metric, used to indicate the complexity of a program. It is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code.

A way to decrease the Cyclomatic complexity is to eliminate the number of unique paths if possible.

The nested IF statements may be adding Time Complexity.

First of all, having nested for-loops will cause a O(N^2) time complexity.It really depends what is the nature of those if statements. If the if statements are O(1) such as checking if a variable is equal to a int, it should have almost no impact to your runtime.

```
for(Object1: Array1){
    for(Object2: Array2){
        if(Object1.number == 20){
            if(Object2.number = 10){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
O(N^2) Time Complexity
```

However if those if statements are iterating over a collection to find a match, it will add an additional layer of O(N) complexity for each collection iteration.

```
for(Object1: Array1){
    for(Object2: Array2){
        if(Array3.contains(Object1)){
            if(Array4.contains(Object2)){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
O(N^4) or more Time Complexity
```

It is important to see what the time complexity of each if statement is. It is even possible that each if statement is worse than O(N) which would negatively impact the performance of your program.